Why must "force_change_password_next_sign_in" be set to false for MS External ID Local Accounts?
See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-3-create-a-customer-account-in-external-tenants

For local account identities, password expirations must be disabled, and force change password at next sign-in must also be disabled

Why is force_change_password_next_sign_in required to be false? Surely a common scenario is to create a local account with a default password, then force that password to be changed on login?

Maybe you can try to set to enable in request parameter and see whether it failed or not, and check whether there's any useful error message inside it. From documentation we can't find the explanation so that we could only guess why it is.

I queried this with Microsoft support and got a response a few days later. Setting it to false is a best practice thing to reduce password resets and such. Not a technical limitation, at least in External ID B2B.

At present it is a limitation in Azure B2C. If you set 'forceChangePasswordNextSignIn' to true when creating the user, it generates a temporary password which is marked as expired. However users don't get the option to reset the password, they only get the message that the password is expired. Please refer the answer in this discussion.
To force a password reset in Azure B2C you need to use the extension attribute 'extension_mustResetPassword'. You can use the guide here.

That's interesting but I'm not entirely sure it's that. External ID External Users are B2B not B2C.

The "force_change_password_next_sign_in" property is set to false for Microsoft Entra External ID Local Accounts because these accounts are for external users like partners or customers. Forcing a password change can disrupt their experience since they usually manage their own passwords using self-service tools. This ensures a smoother and more consistent login process for external users.
